# Can pursuit curves be solved when the escape curve is a trig function?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

The pursuit curve solutions I've seen are all either dealing with escape curves that are linear or circular. Would it be possible to solve one where the escape curve is a sine function for instance?

Comment: You can have the escape curve be whatever you want. Have you figured out what the associated differential equations would be?

Comment: @VarunVejalla I’m still stuck with figuring out the coordinates of the pursued (who is following the sine curve) at time T. I can only figure out the associated differential equations once I have these coordinates, right?

Comment: There are two equations for the pursued: $y=\sin(x)$ and $\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2+\left(\frac{dy}{dt}\right)^2=s^2$ where $x, y$ are functions of $t$ and $s$ is the speed. This doesn't have a closed-form solution, [according to Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=solve+%28x%27%29%5E2*%281%2Bcos%5E2%28x%29%29+%3D+1+for+x).